# Cant deploy my contract: Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I want to deploy my contract on ethereum using hardhat but i got this erros all the time.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQmjo.png)

i tried to upload with remix IDE and i got this:
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H1Nn.png)

my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol';

contract RoboPunksNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 public mintPrice;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public maxSupply;
    uint256 public maxPerWallet;
    bool public isPublicMintEnabled;
    string internal baseTokenUri;
    address payable public withdrawWallet;
    mapping(address => uint256) public walletMints;

    constructor() payable ERC721('RoboPunks', 'RP') {
        mintPrice = 0.02 ether;
        totalSupply = 0;
        maxSupply = 1000;
        maxPerWallet = 3;
        // withrawWallet = 'wallet address'
    }

    function setIsPublicisMintEnabled(bool isPublicMintEnabled_) external onlyOwner {
        isPublicMintEnabled = isPublicMintEnabled_;
    }

    function setBaseTokenUri(string calldata baseTokenUri_) external onlyOwner {
        baseTokenUri = baseTokenUri_;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId_) public view override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId_), 'Token does not exist!');
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseTokenUri, Strings.toString(tokenId_), ".json"));
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = withdrawWallet.call{value: address(this).balance } ('');
        require(success, 'withdraw failed');
    }

    function mint(uint quantity_) public payable {
        require(isPublicMintEnabled, 'minting not enabled');
        require(msg.value == quantity_ * mintPrice, 'wrong mint value');
        require(totalSupply + quantity_ <= maxSupply, 'sold out');
        require(walletMints[msg.sender] + quantity_ <= maxPerWallet, 'exceed max wallet');

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity_; i++) {
            uint256 newTokenId = totalSupply + 1;
            totalSupply++;
            _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        }
        walletMints[msg.sender] += quantity_; 
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to deploy without any erros, i seems im missing something, i cant figure out what that is.

Comment: I can deploy your contract on Remix without error. Can you tell me more about the error? And about the network you use in Remix?

Comment: "jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"err: max fee per gas less than block base fee.

Answer (score 0):

For the error

```
"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"err: max fee per gas less than block base fee. –
```

You can trying increase the GAS LIMIT, for example in Remix is 3000000
[image]